# How to get remote server IP address in bigip_pool_member module using Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, f5

I am looking for to get Ansible inventory IP address while using bigip_pool_member Module. I did loop over inventory group and able to get hostname but unable to fing IP address.

```
- name: Add pool member
      bigip_pool_member:
        state: "present"
        pool: "pool name"
        partition: "Common"
        name: "{{ item }}"
        host: hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] # This one is not working
        port: 80
        provider: "{{ provider }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['test'] }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

**Note**:-
I have windows inventory and gather_facts is trues.

I am getting following erroe,

1. Sometime it is working and adding extra ephemeral node in pool.
2. Sotime throwing hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] is not a valid address

Comment: What is the result you get when running that code? Does it give an unexpected result? Does it fire an error?  Please don't answer in comments, edit your question with more debugging details. In case you get an undefined variable error, did you `gather_facts` on these machines prior to running the above task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, Updaed dynamic inventory creation command with echo ${SERVERS} | tr ', ' '\n' >> ${BUILD_ID}; now able to gfet host IPs – user3305131 55 secs ago